# Function call in mapply returning list not data frame

Tags: r

I have a custom function. When I run the function manually, it returns a data frame:

```
> create_sentiment_df('taggreason', 'republican', 'lost')
Joining, by = "word"
Joining, by = "word"
      sentiment prop.sentiment twitter.name      party election.result
1         anger     0.04721931   taggreason republican            lost
2  anticipation     0.14375656   taggreason republican            lost
3       disgust     0.01259182   taggreason republican            lost
4          fear     0.06190976   taggreason republican            lost
5           joy     0.09024134   taggreason republican            lost
6      negative     0.10073452   taggreason republican            lost
7      positive     0.26862539   taggreason republican            lost
8       sadness     0.03777545   taggreason republican            lost
9      surprise     0.03882476   taggreason republican            lost
10        trust     0.19832109   taggreason republican            lost
```

However, I want to run this multiple times, so I am using `mapply` on each row of a data frame. Here is the data, with a data frame of only 1 row (for testing):

```
> datt1
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  twtr_handle party      result district_flipped
  <chr>       <chr>      <chr>  <chr>           
1 taggreason  republican lost   flipped
```

And then the function call:

```
rslt <- mapply(create_sentiment_df, datt1$twtr_handle, datt1$party, datt1$result)
```

Which returns:

```
> rslt
                taggreason  
sentiment       Character,10
prop.sentiment  Numeric,10  
twitter.name    Character,10
party           Character,10
election.result Character,10
```

or:

[image]

Below is the function. It requires twitter authorization, so I'm not sure how it can easily be rerun. Is there anything about the function itself that would make `mapply` return a list rather than a data frame?

```
library(rtweet)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
library(BBmisc)
library(reshape)

create_token(
  app = "Flippable Sentiment Analysis",
  consumer_key = c_k,
  consumer_secret = c_s,
  access_token <- a_t,
  access_secret <- a_s)

create_sentiment_df <- function(twitter.name, party, election.result) {
  va_stop_words <- stop_words %>% select(-lexicon) %>% 
    bind_rows(data.frame(word = c("https", "t.co", "rt", "amp")))
  nrc_lex <- get_sentiments("nrc") # many sentiments

  dat <- get_timeline(twitter.name, n=3200)
  dat$created_at <- as.Date(dat$created_at)
  dat_2017 <- subset(dat, created_at > as.Date('2017-01-01') & created_at < as.Date('2017-11-06'))

  dat_words <- dat_2017 %>% 
    select(status_id, text) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word,text)

  dat_words_interesting <- dat_words %>% anti_join(va_stop_words)
  dat_sentiment <- dat_words_interesting %>% left_join(nrc_lex)
  dat_sentiment_count <- dat_sentiment %>% 
    filter(!is.na(sentiment)) %>% 
    group_by(sentiment) %>% 
    summarise(prop.sentiment=n())
  dat_sentiment_count <- na.omit(dat_sentiment_count)

  dat_sentiment_count <- cbind(dat_sentiment_count[1], 
                            prop.table(data.matrix(dat_sentiment_count[-1]), margin=2))

  # dat_sentiment_count$twitter.name <- NA
  dat_sentiment_count$twitter.name <- twitter.name
  dat_sentiment_count$party <- party
  dat_sentiment_count$election.result <- election.result

  return(as.data.frame(dat_sentiment_count))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create_sentiment_df` function returns a data.frame and `mapply` simplifies it by default.

If you need the list of data.frames, you can do:

```
mapply(create_sentiment_df, datt1$twtr_handle, datt1$party, datt1$result, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

If you require a single data.frame for all your data.frame outputs, use:

```
do.call(rbind, mapply(create_sentiment_df, datt1$twtr_handle,
                      datt1$party, datt1$result, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't realize that about mapply